# Pivot table in stored procedure using view manage null value

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

This stored procedure result store in total on the basis of query , if there in no any record in total
then  want 0 in result,how can manage null value .

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Procedure_Summary
    @UserID INT ,
    @Year INT    
AS
BEGIN

/* Procedure body */   

SELECT  UserID, 
        UserName ,
        [Marks1] as 'English',
        [Marks2] as 'Maths',
        [Marks3] as 'Science'
FROM 
    ( 
        SELECT l.UserID, 
                e.UserName , 
                s.SubjectName, 
                TotalMarks AS Total
        FROM ViewLeave l
            INNER JOIN  SubjectType  s  ON s.SubjectID = l.SubjectID  
            INNER JOIN UserInfo e ON e.UserID = l.UserID
        WHERE (( l.Result = 'Pass') 
                AND ( e.UserID = @UserID)
                AND l.[year]=@Year)
        GROUP BY s.SubjectName,l.UserID, e.UserName ,TotalDays
    )ps
    pivot
    (
        SUM(Total)
        FOR SubjectName IN ([Marks1],[Marks2],[Marks3])
    ) AS pvt           

END
```

> Current result and expected result are as -

```
Accoding to current stored procedure result are as ,

UserID          UserName    English     Maths       Science 
105                 ABC     25      0       36
106                 XYZ     26      88      88

But i want if all three subject marks are 0 means total are zero and then show 
as , also show non zero record 


UserID          UserName    English     Maths       Science 
109                  QWE          0     0       0
```

Comment: Can you post some data for each table and the desired result?  It is possible that changing your `INNER JOIN`s to `LEFT JOIN`s might suffice.

Comment: LEFT JOIN tried but not get any result

Comment: My suggestion would be to post some sample data and the desired result.   or better yet create a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) with a working data model.

Comment: If you run the inner query for user 109, do you return any data? Also why are you using a GROUP BY in the inner query?  Can you post data for each table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Procedure_Summary @UserID INT , @Year INT    AS BEGIN

          /* Procedure body */   
            SELECT  UserID, UserName ,  [Marks1] as 'English',
                [Marks2] as 'Maths',
                [Marks3] as 'Science'  FROM   
    ( SELECT l.UserID,  e.UserName ,   s.SubjectName,  
     case when l.Result = 'Pass' 
     then l.TotalMarks   
    else 0  end  AS Total 
      from  UserInfo e  
 LEFT  JOIN  ViewLeave l   ON e.UserID = l.UserID 
  LEFT  JOIN SubjectType  s  ON s.SubjectID = l.SubjectID    

              Where   e.UserID = @UserD  AND 
               l.year=@Year
                 GROUP BY s.SubjectName,l.UserID, e.UserName ,TotalDays
            )ps
            pivot
            (
                SUM(Total)
                FOR SubjectName IN ([Marks1],[Marks2],[Marks3])
            ) AS pvt           

        END
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Procedure_Summary

    @UserID INT ,
    @Year INT    

AS BEGIN

    SELECT  
          UserID
        , UserName 
        , [English] = [Marks1]
        , [Maths] = [Marks2]
        , [Science] = [Marks3]
    FROM 
    ( 
        SELECT 
              l.UserID
            , e.UserName 
            , s.SubjectName
            , Total = ISNULL(TotalMarks, 0) 
        FROM dbo.ViewLeave l
        LEFT JOIN dbo.SubjectType s ON s.SubjectID = l.SubjectID  
        LEFT JOIN dbo.UserInfo e ON e.UserID = l.UserID
        WHERE l.Result = 'Pass' 
            AND e.UserID = @UserID
            AND l.[year] = @Year
        GROUP BY 
              s.SubjectName
            , l.UserID
            , e.UserName 
            , TotalDays
    ) ps
    PIVOT
    (
        SUM(Total)
        FOR SubjectName In ([Marks1],[Marks2],[Marks3])
    ) pvt           

END
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data form your tables.

Comment: Try to use GROUP BY ALL - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175028%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to fully answer this because the details of the tables are not great.

You can try to run your inner query with the user that you are passing in to see if any data gets returned:

```
SELECT l.UserID, 
   e.UserName , 
   s.SubjectName, 
   TotalMarks AS Total
FROM ViewLeave l
INNER JOIN  SubjectType  s  ON s.SubjectID = l.SubjectID  
INNER JOIN UserInfo e ON e.UserID = l.UserID
WHERE (( l.Result = 'Pass') 
   AND ( e.UserID = @UserID)
   AND l.[year]=@Year)
GROUP BY s.SubjectName,l.UserID, e.UserName ,TotalDays  -- I am not sure why you have this group by
```

I am guessing that part of the problem is the way you are JOINing. You are using an inner join which will require the rows to be present in each table but the user is being filtered by the `UserInfo` table. So I would propose the following changes.

Change your JOINs to LEFT JOINs and make the first table joined be the `UserInfo` table, so the code will be:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Procedure_Summary
    @UserID INT ,
    @Year INT    
AS
BEGIN

/* Procedure body */   

SELECT  UserID, 
        UserName ,
        [Marks1] as 'English',
        [Marks2] as 'Maths',
        [Marks3] as 'Science'
FROM 
    ( 
        SELECT l.UserID, 
                e.UserName , 
                s.SubjectName, 
                TotalMarks AS Total
        FROM UserInfo e
        LEFT JOIN ViewLeave l 
          ON e.UserID = l.UserID
          AND l.Result = 'Pass'
          AND l.[year]=@Year
        LEFT JOIN  SubjectType  s  
          ON s.SubjectID = l.SubjectID  
        WHERE e.UserID = @UserID
    )ps
    pivot
    (
        SUM(Total)
        FOR SubjectName IN ([Marks1],[Marks2],[Marks3])
    ) AS pvt           

END
```